# Ajax GET with Authorization header

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, postman

I use the Chrome extension Postman to generate code for POST and GET requests with the appropiate headers, but after hours of working with this I see I'm gonna need help. It works perfectly in Postman, but the Javascript code it provides is somehow wrong.

If I make the request without the Authentication header I get a GET 401 - Unauthorized.

If I make the request with the Authentication header I get a OPTIONS 401 - Unauthorized.

```
        $.ajax(
        {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://mywebservice.com/example.php?key=myValue",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": 
            {
                "authorization": "Basic YWRtaW39NjU1YzVlMWM="
            }
        })
```

Can anyone explain why I get a 401 Options when I use the correct Authorization header? I have also tried using `btoa(username + ":" + password)` - same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is stopping you from making a cross-domain request to protect you from security vulnerabilities.
(This doesn't happen in postman, because postman is a browser extension, and thus has different permissions than a standard webpage.)

<strike>There are a few ways around this :

 1. If both domains are under your control, then make use of the
    [Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) 

 2. Use [jsonp](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) to make
    the call</strike>

Comment: You can't set custom headers with JSONP. Using Access-Cointrol-Allow-Origin won't prevent the OPTIONS request from being made.

Comment: Thank you very much gillyb! I added "dataType": "jsonp" and it works perfectly now! Thanks a lot for your help :)